# Why is my code resulting in a horizontal list instead of a vertical one?

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a script to pull in all the file names from a directory, modify the name, and then output the name to an Excel file. As of right now, I'm simply focused on getting the list of file names to output to a .csv file, and when I do this, the files names appear in a horizontal list, one item in each column, instead of a vertical list, one item in each row under a header.

I tried both using the writer.writerow(files) and for i in files: writer.writerow(i). First one gave me the current horizontal output, while the second one broke up each character into a new cell, horizontally, while write the list vertically.

```py
import os
import csv

path = "C:\\Users\\[REST OF PATH]\\"

files = []
csv_filename = "python_list_test.csv"

#r = root, d = directory, f = files

''' * for r,d,f, in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.txt' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r,file))
for f in files:
    print(f)
'''

for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for name in f:
        if '.pdf' in name:
            files.append(name)

for i in files:
    print(i)

with open(csv_filename, mode='w',newline='') as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    writer.writerow(['File Name',])

    writer.writerow(files)
```

I expected the code to give me a single column list with each row being the next item. When I print the second method I mentioned earlier(for i in files:...), it looks perfect, but writing to a .csv file separated out the characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to change the last row:

```python
writer.writerows([f] for f in files)
```

Comment: Really? haha. Let me try that. I just tested changing it to this and it worked as well. 

```python
for i in files:
    writer.writerow([i])
```
Which is the better way to go about it?

Comment: Oh, that didn't work. It went back to writing each character into a single cell horizontally.

Comment: Nothing different in Python 2.7 actually. However in Python 3 the csv module is partly rewritten in C, therefore using `writerows` can give you a little bit boost.

Comment: @dnlarralde: Oh I forgot to convert the string to list.

Comment: Oh gotcha. That looks way neater. I like that. I wonder why writerows didn't show up as an option in the Pycharm suggestions.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for the info!